# Any risks to storing glass carboys and other brew equipment in an unheated garage?

Tags: equipment, storage

We currently have all of our brewing equipment big pile in a spare room and have finally made space for it in our garage (as well as purchased some additional equipment for brewing there). We have a table we're planning to put everything on/under but since the garage is unheated we were concerned about the potential for large temperature ranges affecting the equipment, especially empty glass carboys (for now we're still planning to ferment in a closet).

What problems could we run into by keeping things in the garage? The cold months seem most concerning, especially for the carboys but I could imagine summer heat be an issue as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have issue with natural tempurature swings on empty glass carboys.

I store clean sanitized and dry with foil and rubber band on top. In the high desert which can reach 100+ day time and 30-40° at night.

Comment: High desert? Where do you live?!

Comment: @Mołot So cal, yucca

Comment: I also stored cleaned glass carboys in a detached garage and the temperature varies between over 100+ in the summer and as low as single digits in the winter.